# I want to build an app that just load my existing website with flutter

Tags: flutter

I have a website, I need to make an app for mobile devices with flutter, that just displays my website.

I guess my app is a hybrid app, that uses webview to load my website.
I've made that with flutter, but I'm facing some troubles with the back key in android, it is exit to phone home screen.
I've used webview_flutter plugin

Answer (score 4):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can Wrap `Scaffold` with `WillPopScope` and when user click device back button you can  execute WebView Controller's goback `controllerGlobal.goBack();`

code snippet

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () => _exitApp(context),
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Flutter WebView example'),
          // This drop down menu demonstrates that Flutter widgets can be shown over the web view.
          actions: <Widget>[
            NavigationControls(_controller.future),
            SampleMenu(_controller.future),
          ],
        ),

...
WebViewController controllerGlobal;
... 
Future<bool> _exitApp(BuildContext context) async {
  if (await controllerGlobal.canGoBack()) {
    print("onwill goback");
    controllerGlobal.goBack();
  } else {
    Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
      const SnackBar(content: Text("No back history item")),
    );
    return Future.value(false);
  }
}
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: WebViewExample()));

const String kNavigationExamplePage = '''
<!DOCTYPE html><html>
<head><title>Navigation Delegate Example</title></head>
<body>
<p>
The navigation delegate is set to block navigation to the youtube website.
</p>
<ul>
<ul><a href="https://www.youtube.com/">https://www.youtube.com/</a></ul>
<ul><a href="https://www.google.com/">https://www.google.com/</a></ul>
<ul><a href="https://www.google.com/">https://nodejs.org/en</a></ul>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
''';

class WebViewExample extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _WebViewExampleState createState() => _WebViewExampleState();
}

WebViewController controllerGlobal;

Future<bool> _exitApp(BuildContext context) async {
  if (await controllerGlobal.canGoBack()) {
    print("onwill goback");
    controllerGlobal.goBack();
  } else {
    Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
      const SnackBar(content: Text("No back history item")),
    );
    return Future.value(false);
  }
}

class _WebViewExampleState extends State<WebViewExample> {
  final Completer<WebViewController> _controller =
  Completer<WebViewController>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () => _exitApp(context),
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Flutter WebView example'),
          // This drop down menu demonstrates that Flutter widgets can be shown over the web view.
          actions: <Widget>[
            NavigationControls(_controller.future),
            SampleMenu(_controller.future),
          ],
        ),
        // We're using a Builder here so we have a context that is below the Scaffold
        // to allow calling Scaffold.of(context) so we can show a snackbar.
        body: Builder(builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return WebView(
            initialUrl: 'https://flutter.dev',
            javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
            onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
              _controller.complete(webViewController);
            },
            // TODO(iskakaushik): Remove this when collection literals makes it to stable.
            // ignore: prefer_collection_literals
            javascriptChannels: <JavascriptChannel>[
              _toasterJavascriptChannel(context),
            ].toSet(),
            navigationDelegate: (NavigationRequest request) {
              if (request.url.startsWith('https://www.youtube.com/')) {
                print('blocking navigation to $request}');
                return NavigationDecision.prevent;
              }
              if (request.url.startsWith('https://flutter.dev/docs')) {
                print('blocking navigation to $request}');
                return NavigationDecision.prevent;
              }
              print('allowing navigation to $request');
              return NavigationDecision.navigate;
            },
            onPageFinished: (String url) {
              print('Page finished loading: $url');
            },
          );
        }),
        floatingActionButton: favoriteButton(),
      ),
    );
  }

  JavascriptChannel _toasterJavascriptChannel(BuildContext context) {
    return JavascriptChannel(
        name: 'Toaster',
        onMessageReceived: (JavascriptMessage message) {
          Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
            SnackBar(content: Text(message.message)),
          );
        });
  }

  Widget favoriteButton() {
    return FutureBuilder<WebViewController>(
        future: _controller.future,
        builder: (BuildContext context,
            AsyncSnapshot<WebViewController> controller) {
          if (controller.hasData) {
            return FloatingActionButton(
              onPressed: () async {
                final String url = await controller.data.currentUrl();
                Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
                  SnackBar(content: Text('Favorited $url')),
                );
              },
              child: const Icon(Icons.favorite),
            );
          }
          return Container();
        });
  }
}

enum MenuOptions {
  showUserAgent,
  listCookies,
  clearCookies,
  addToCache,
  listCache,
  clearCache,
  navigationDelegate,
}

class SampleMenu extends StatelessWidget {
  SampleMenu(this.controller);

  final Future<WebViewController> controller;
  final CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<WebViewController>(
      future: controller,
      builder:
          (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<WebViewController> controller) {
        return PopupMenuButton<MenuOptions>(
          onSelected: (MenuOptions value) {
            switch (value) {
              case MenuOptions.showUserAgent:
                _onShowUserAgent(controller.data, context);
                break;
              case MenuOptions.listCookies:
                _onListCookies(controller.data, context);
                break;
              case MenuOptions.clearCookies:
                _onClearCookies(context);
                break;
              case MenuOptions.addToCache:
                _onAddToCache(controller.data, context);
                break;
              case MenuOptions.listCache:
                _onListCache(controller.data, context);
                break;
              case MenuOptions.clearCache:
                _onClearCache(controller.data, context);
                break;
              case MenuOptions.navigationDelegate:
                _onNavigationDelegateExample(controller.data, context);
                break;
            }
          },
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) => <PopupMenuItem<MenuOptions>>[
            PopupMenuItem<MenuOptions>(
              value: MenuOptions.showUserAgent,
              child: const Text('Show user agent'),
              enabled: controller.hasData,
            ),
            const PopupMenuItem<MenuOptions>(
              value: MenuOptions.listCookies,
              child: Text('List cookies'),
            ),
            const PopupMenuItem<MenuOptions>(
              value: MenuOptions.clearCookies,
              child: Text('Clear cookies'),
            ),
            const PopupMenuItem<MenuOptions>(
              value: MenuOptions.addToCache,
              child: Text('Add to cache'),
            ),
            const PopupMenuItem<MenuOptions>(
              value: MenuOptions.listCache,
              child: Text('List cache'),
            ),
            const PopupMenuItem<MenuOptions>(
              value: MenuOptions.clearCache,
              child: Text('Clear cache'),
            ),
            const PopupMenuItem<MenuOptions>(
              value: MenuOptions.navigationDelegate,
              child: Text('Navigation Delegate example'),
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }

  void _onShowUserAgent(
      WebViewController controller, BuildContext context) async {
    // Send a message with the user agent string to the Toaster JavaScript channel we registered
    // with the WebView.
    controller.evaluateJavascript(
        'Toaster.postMessage("User Agent: " + navigator.userAgent);');
  }

  void _onListCookies(
      WebViewController controller, BuildContext context) async {
    final String cookies =
    await controller.evaluateJavascript('document.cookie');
    Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
      content: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: <Widget>[
          const Text('Cookies:'),
          _getCookieList(cookies),
        ],
      ),
    ));
  }

  void _onAddToCache(WebViewController controller, BuildContext context) async {
    await controller.evaluateJavascript(
        'caches.open("test_caches_entry"); localStorage["test_localStorage"] = "dummy_entry";');
    Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(const SnackBar(
      content: Text('Added a test entry to cache.'),
    ));
  }

  void _onListCache(WebViewController controller, BuildContext context) async {
    await controller.evaluateJavascript('caches.keys()'
        '.then((cacheKeys) => JSON.stringify({"cacheKeys" : cacheKeys, "localStorage" : localStorage}))'
        '.then((caches) => Toaster.postMessage(caches))');
  }

  void _onClearCache(WebViewController controller, BuildContext context) async {
    await controller.clearCache();
    Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(const SnackBar(
      content: Text("Cache cleared."),
    ));
  }

  void _onClearCookies(BuildContext context) async {
    final bool hadCookies = await cookieManager.clearCookies();
    String message = 'There were cookies. Now, they are gone!';
    if (!hadCookies) {
      message = 'There are no cookies.';
    }
    Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
      content: Text(message),
    ));
  }

  void _onNavigationDelegateExample(
      WebViewController controller, BuildContext context) async {
    final String contentBase64 =
    base64Encode(const Utf8Encoder().convert(kNavigationExamplePage));
    controller.loadUrl('data:text/html;base64,$contentBase64');
  }

  Widget _getCookieList(String cookies) {
    if (cookies == null || cookies == '""') {
      return Container();
    }
    final List<String> cookieList = cookies.split(';');
    final Iterable<Text> cookieWidgets =
    cookieList.map((String cookie) => Text(cookie));
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: cookieWidgets.toList(),
    );
  }
}



class NavigationControls extends StatelessWidget {
  const NavigationControls(this._webViewControllerFuture)
      : assert(_webViewControllerFuture != null);

  final Future<WebViewController> _webViewControllerFuture;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<WebViewController>(
      future: _webViewControllerFuture,
      builder:
          (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<WebViewController> snapshot) {
        final bool webViewReady =
            snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done;
        final WebViewController controller = snapshot.data;
        controllerGlobal = controller;

        return Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
              icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios),
              onPressed: !webViewReady
                  ? null
                  : () async {
                if (await controller.canGoBack()) {
                  controller.goBack();
                } else {
                  Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
                    const SnackBar(content: Text("No back history item")),
                  );
                  return;
                }
              },
            ),
            IconButton(
              icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios),
              onPressed: !webViewReady
                  ? null
                  : () async {
                if (await controller.canGoForward()) {
                  controller.goForward();
                } else {
                  Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
                    const SnackBar(
                        content: Text("No forward history item")),
                  );
                  return;
                }
              },
            ),
            IconButton(
              icon: const Icon(Icons.replay),
              onPressed: !webViewReady
                  ? null
                  : () {
                controller.reload();
              },
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```